# pthread Linker problems within visual studio 2012

Tags: c, visual-studio-2012, linker

I've read many posts telling me to go to linker->input->Additional dependendancies and add the pthreadVC2.lib file which I did do, but I'm still getting the exact same errors. Does anyone know what the problem is? Sorry I'm new to pthread and stack overflow
These are my errors & code:

```
1>  main.cpp
```

`1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__pthread_create referenced in function _main`

`1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__pthread_exit referenced in function "void * __cdecl PrintHello(void *)" (?PrintHello@@YAPAXPAX@Z)`

`1>C:\Users\Gdizzle\Google Drive\Documents\Programming\Game\Project1\Debug\Project1.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals`

```
`#include <pthread.h>`

`#include <stdio.h>`
`#define NUM_THREADS     5`


void *PrintHello(void *threadid)
{
   long tid;

   tid = (long)threadid;

   printf("Hello World! It's me, thread #%ld!\n", tid);

   pthread_exit(NULL);

   return threadid;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
   pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];

   int rc;
   long t;
   `for(t=0; t<NUM_THREADS; t++){`

      printf("In main: creating thread %ld\n", t);

      rc = pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL, PrintHello, (void *)t);
      if (rc){
         printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", rc);
         exit(-1);
         return 1;
      }
   }

   /* Last thing that main() should do */
   pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

The linker commandLine says this:

/OUT:"C:\Users\Gdizzle\Google Drive\Documents\Programming\Game\Project1\Debug\Project1.exe" /MANIFEST /NXCOMPAT /PDB:"C:\Users\Gdizzle\Google Drive\Documents\Programming\Game\Project1\Debug\Project1.pdb" /DYNAMICBASE "pthreadVC2.lib" "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib" /DEBUG /MACHINE:X86 /INCREMENTAL /PGD:"C:\Users\Gdizzle\Google Drive\Documents\Programming\Game\Project1\Debug\Project1.pgd" /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /ManifestFile:"Debug\Project1.exe.intermediate.manifest" /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /NOLOGO /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\lib" /TLBID:1

Comment: What does "Linker->Command Line" show you?

Comment: And did you add the reference to `pthreadVC2.lib` using its full path?

Comment: I attempted to use the full path, but it won't link if I use the full path.

Comment: I think you should use mingw ...

Comment: This works here using VS2010. Which error did you get when having used the full Path?

Comment: Idk about 2012. When I use the full path the error just says:fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\pthreadVC2.lib'

Comment: @user3118190: This obviously indicates the path provided is wrong. Or access rights aren't set properly (which I doubt on windows ;-)) Anyway double check it.

Comment: I tried giving all permissions to the folder. I also did a run as administrator. No improvement. I just downloaded msvs 2013. I'll try it on there too.

Comment: I tried 2013. It does the same thing